# p4v cannot see the default tree in pending tab

Tags: perforce, p4v

I am new to P4V (perforce) while working with this, i cannot see the default folder in pending tab as i cannt drag any files for editing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you created a workspace? Open workspaces tab > right click.

Also make sure your connection is set up properly.